# Why is 4 the most recurring UUID character?

Tags: java, uuid

I wrote a small program in Java that generates 5000 random UUIDs and finds the most recurring character in them overall and I always get as a result that the most recurring character after "-" ( always 20.000 occurencies obviously ) is "4" ( I ran the program several times always getting the same result ).

I was just curious about this fact and was wondering if someone had a technical explanation or if it's really just a coincidence.

Thanks!

This is the function I used to generate the 5000 random UUIDs.

```
 UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Comment: [UUID algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) might help

Comment: Please show your program so we can explain the behavior. I hope you've read at least Wikipedia shared by @MadProgrammer and cut out non-random parts of UUID in your code (4 is pretty much guaranteed to happen more often due to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random) if you did not do that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because UUIDs aren't *entirely* random. Check the [Universally unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) on wikipedia which explains the various versions.

They look like:

`xxxxxxxx-xxxx-Mxxx-Nxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

Where the M and the N are definitely not random (they indicate versions and variants), and the rest may not be random either depending on the mode you're using. The code you write gets you version 4, which means 'M' is always 4, and half of 'N' is also unchanging. You get 122 bits of randomness; not 128.

4 is the most common digit because the 13th 'digit' is always a 4, as per the UUID design.